# Saving partial result of df.apply after exception

Tags: python, pandas, exception

How to get the partial result computed by `df.apply()` when an Exception is raised within the function?

### Context

I have a Pandas dataframe where values are missing. To get this values I have to call a REST API for each row (which take time). To do that, I use the `apply()` function.
Exceptions can be thrown during the API call, or the scipt can be stopped with CTRL-C.
I would like to save the results that have been acquired so far before closing the process, however `apply()` will not return a value if an exception is raised. Do I have to use a for loop?

The example code is the following:

```py
import random
import time 
import pandas as pd

# Simulate a request to a slow REST API taking parameters, returning an integer and where exceptions can be raised
def getApiValue_sim(p1:int, p2:int) -> int:
    time.sleep(1) #Simulate slow request
    i = random.randint(p1,p2) #Simulate REST API reply
    if not i%4:
        raise Exception("Multiple of 4") #Simulate exception raising
    return i

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'P1':[1,2,3],'P2':[11, 12, 13],'Reply':[pd.NA,pd.NA,pd.NA]})

try:
    dataframe['Reply'] = dataframe.apply(lambda row : getApiValue_sim(row['P1'],row['P2']), axis=1) #Do not return a value if an exception occure
finally:
    print(dataframe)
```

Comment: Don't do this. Build the new list separately and then assign it back to a new column; otherwise you just have a headache on your hands. `apply()` is just a python loop anyway so you're not losing any efficiency. It's not a vectorized operation in the sense of efficiency

Comment: The way I would normally do this is use `requests-futures` iterating over the row values and building the new list asynchronously from API calls. I can handle errors and retries in my own logic, then assign it back. That will be much faster anyway than serial calls with `apply()` even if you get this working

Comment: I didn't know about `requests-futures`, it's true that it's much more efficient to make the API calls asynchronously. Tks for the advice

Comment: There are other ways such as `asyncio` and it does (marginally) win in the benchmarks I've seen in the past but we're talking like 5% faster for the newer approach IIRC and I can't be bothered with the extra work it took. Normally I'm firing requests faster than the server anyway so it makes little difference